# wsDualHttpBinding binding = new wsDualHttpBinding()?

Tags: wcf-binding

I dont have visual studio but I would like to host a wsDualHttpBinding binding with code.
The thing is I am getting an error when I compile:

> error cs0246:the type or namespace name wsdualhttovinding could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assemvly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a reference to `System.ServiceModel` and if that is indeed the exact error, you need to check your spelling of `WSDualHttpBinding`

[WSDualHttpBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx)

Comment: thank you that helped. Sorry for the TYPO